# pyqt4: Loop main Render class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, pyqt4

I have a PyQt4 class that downloads webpages that I use for scrapping purposes.

When I pass a list of urls to the Render class while instantiating it works fine(single call) but when I try to loop the [r = Render(url, cb=scrape)]with a multiple list of urls, after the first loop,the execution stops or hangs without any error thrown.

I want to loop the class separately because the urls list belong to different category and will have to store the contents extracted separately.

I also came to know that only one app can be initiated, if that is the case how to exit the app without quitting it. so that new url list can be used by the same app

I am stuck with this issue for a while. Thanks in advance

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, urls, cb):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.urls = urls  
    self.cb = cb
    self.crawl()  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def crawl(self):  
    if self.urls:  
      url = self.urls.pop(0)  
      print 'Downloading', url  
      self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    else:  
      self.app.quit()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    frame = self.mainFrame()  
    url = str(frame.url().toString())  
    html = frame.toHtml()  
    self.cb(url, html)
    self.crawl()  

def scrape(url, html):
    pass # have scraping code here

url1 = ['http://webscraping.com', 'http://webscraping.com/blog'] 
url2 = ['http://webscraping.com', 'http://webscraping.com/blog']
urls =[]
urls.append(url1)
urls.append(url2)

for url in urls:
    r = Render(url, cb=scrape)
```

Comment: Why do you create a `QApplication` inside `Render` ? Why no just once, outside the class ? This might be the issue.

Comment: Even if we create an app outside render, app.quit() needs to be called to exit the processing loop of a url list. only if the loop stops , the next list of urls can be passed. But the problem is once app.quit() is called, it terminates the app and a new app cant be created. So, I would like to know is there a way to exit the loop without quitting the app?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `QWepPage`, but it seems to me you could simply remove the `else: self.app.quit()`. If `self.urls` is False, then `load` is not called, and `loadFinished` is not emitted, therefore the loop exit.

Comment: @Mel if app.quit was removed then execution would never return to the main loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can only instantiate a single QApplication object. Here is an updated version that avoids this and then only runs Qt's execution loop when downloading a URL:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, cb):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.cb = cb

  def crawl(self, url):
    print 'Downloading', url
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    frame = self.mainFrame()
    url = str(frame.url().toString())
    html = frame.toHtml()
    self.cb(url, html)
    self.app.quit()


def scrape(url, html):
  pass # add scraping code here
  print len(html)


r = Render(cb=scrape)
urls = ['http://webscraping.com', 'http://webscraping.com/blog']
for url in urls:
    r.crawl(url)
```

Comment: This is really great @hoju. However, I seem to be running into a problem with different urls. If I add `'http://themonkeycage.org/` or `https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/` to the URL list, the process seems to hang. Is there a timeout problem? Happy to post another question...

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, @hoju 's answer did not work for me.

here is what works for me (basically setting up a timer to check if loading has completed).

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.frame = None
        self.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()

def go_again():
    global r, timer, urls
    if(len(urls)>0):
        print("loading",urls[0])
        r = Render(urls.pop())
        timer.start(1000)
    else:
        print("finished")
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

def check_done():
    global r, timer
    if r.frame is not None:
        timer.stop()
        html_result = r.frame.toHtml()
        #do something with html
        print("loaded")
        go_again()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603886/pyqt4-loop-main-render-class','http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603886/pyqt4-loop-main-render-class']

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(check_done)
#check every second
go_again()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```